# JQuery add class to active link

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to add  an `active` class to an link but i can't get it working.

Let's say that I've got the following HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="menu_li"> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_li dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="cursor: pointer;">Partijen<span class="caret"></span> </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/partijen/1">Actief</a>
</li>
            <li> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/partijen/0">Inactief</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/telers">Telers</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/handelshuis">Handelshuis</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/ras">Ras</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/klasse">Klasse</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/perceel">Perceel</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/maat">Maat</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/behandeling">Behandeling</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_li"> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/bewaarplaatsen">Bewaarplaatsen</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_li"> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/proin">Product in</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_li"> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/proout">Product uit</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_li"> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/taken">Taken</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_li"> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/historie">Historie</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I've got the following JS:

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location.href.replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log("url: " + url);
    // now grab every link from the navigation
    $('.menu_li a').each(function () {
        console.log("this href: " + this.href);
        if (this.href.indexOf(url) > 0) {
            console.log("Hit!");
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });

});
```

Let's say that I've navigated to this URL:

```
http://192.168.215.248/public/taken
```

Then i wan't to add the `active` class onto this element:

```
<li class="menu_li"> <a href="http://192.168.215.248/public/taken">Taken</a></li>
```

But that won't happen... The output i get is:

```
url: http://192.168.215.248/public/taken
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public
this href:
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/partijen/1
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/partijen/0
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/telers
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/handelshuis
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/ras
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/klasse
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/perceel
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/maat
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/behandeling
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/bewaarplaatsen
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/proin
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/proout
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/taken
this href: http://192.168.215.248/public/historie
```

[Here's an JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qttD8/1/)

As you can see, should i get an hit. The reason I'm not checking with `if(url == hrefurl)` is because the navigation url can also be:

```
http://192.168.215.248/public/taken/edit/200
or
http://192.168.215.248/public/taken/nieuw
```

and so on.

I have an feeling I've got to do something with regex, but I'm no pro in JS, let alone in regex....

So does anybody know how I can make this piece of JS work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The match with `indexOf` gives output as `0` if string is found; else `-1`,

so the condition should be

```
if (this.href.indexOf(url) > -1)
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qttD8/2/)**

Comment: Damm, I was so close, but yet so far away... Thank you for pointing that out. And do you know how I can make it work with the other to links (`link_visiting_2 and link_visiting_3` )?

Comment: Try passing them in an array. And match `thishref` with array contents.

Comment: Sorry If i wasn't clear. I don't need to test to multiple variables. But the url that i'm visiting can be like this: `http://192.168.215.248/public/taken`, but can also be like this: `http://192.168.215.248/public/taken/edit/200`. And in both conditions, I wan't to "activate" the `http://192.168.215.248/public/taken` link...

Comment: Ohh sorry, then the above code will work in that case. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/qttD8/3/. Every url with `http://192.168.215.248/public/taken` in it will be activated

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. You saved me an headache today!